# Invoking a REST api GET method with a JSON Body .net framework

Tags: c#, .net

I've been searching for hours in stackoverflow and google but could not make this work:

I have a server that I need to call through a REST API.
It has an endpoint that I need to invoke through a GET method and I need to pass a body within the request. I do not have access to the person who developed the server, and I just need to invoke this.

I know a GET call with body is against the standard, but I have to live with it as the server is currently expecting it.

It works perfectly well in postman, but I cannot make it work in a .net framework 4.7.2 app.

Here's my postman request:

[image: Postman Request]

When I run this in .net it either gets a protocol violation (image below) or it never gets a response and it gets stuck at _lient.SendAsync(...) (second image below).

[image: api invocation 1]

Gets stuck:
[image: gets stuck]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In Postman it seems you have some header entries. According to the code, they seem to be missing. Maybe this is the error. Also to better compare what is different in the requests you should run Fiddler and compare Postman with C# request.

Comment: all headers are the same :(. I also tried using RestSharp but found no success

Comment: The documentation for [`HttpWebRequest.GetResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse) does say that a `ProtocolViolationException` is thrown if the Content Length is `>= 0` on a GET or HEAD. For `HttpClient`, maybe something like [`Network Tracing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/enabling-network-tracing) could help you troubleshoot?

Comment: I'm looking for some alternative that allows me to send the GET request with a body, even if it's a ProtocolViolation. Since Postman can do it with no trouble, I have a hard time believing that it cannot be achieved in C# :(, seems crazy to have to jump through so many hoops, as well as the fact that Client-side it is being limited. I would definitely expect a server to ignore that data, but not a client to prevent from sending